# How to render URL ALIAS field on form?

Tags: forms, path-aliases

Is there a way to render the URL Alias field on the form separately from the `print drupal_render_children($form);`?

My plan is to render the URL Alias field on top of the form neatly (before the other fields), bcoz right now its in some sort of box like output that is generated by Drupal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you in the right way you want to edit path alias when creating new content. 
At first you have to give permission to create and edit URL aliases to some user role.

[image]
Then just add `<?php print drupal_render($form['path']); ?>` to your form template (EG. to the top of the form).